# Angular passing dynamic entry components into module and then passing them again into another module

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making a modal component for a component library. I made a 3rd party modal library that I'm using within my component library. A main feature is being able to pass a component via a service and dynamically adding it to the modal.

My modal lib has a static method that allows you to add your component to the module's entry components. It looks like:

```
export class A11yModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: A11yModalModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        useValue: components,
        multi: true
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

Cool, that works. I can pass components into it when I import the module like this: `A11yModalModule.withComponents([ModalContentComponent])`

My problem occurs when I abstract this out another level. So now instead of 2 modules I have 3. I need to pass a component like I did above from the lib consumer's module, to my component module, and then into the modal module.

How can I pass components from the lib module to the modal module?

---

I think I'm getting close. Here are my 3 modules

```
// app module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalContentComponent],
  imports: [
    LibModalModule.withComponents([ModalContentComponent])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



// lib module
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [LibModal],
  providers: [LibModalService],
  exports: []
})
export class LibModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModalModule,
      imports: [CommonModule, A11yModalModule.withComponents(components)]
    };
  }
}



// a11y modal module
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [ModalComponent],
  exports: [],
  providers: [ModalService, DomService],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent]
})
export class A11yModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: A11yModalModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        useValue: components,
        multi: true
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Since NG 9 Ivy compiler deprecated the ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS. (for someone looking at this excellent question in the future) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`withComponents` method should return `ModuleWithProviders` object which is just wrapper around a module that also includes the providers.

It can't have `imports` property or something else because it doesn't understand those properties. Here's an [excerpt](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/439030fb57a007bf2d9c7d85aa36bbb76e2a914a/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L528-L537) from angular source code that is responsible from reading metadata from `ModuleWithProviders`:

```
else if (importedType && importedType.ngModule) {
  const moduleWithProviders: ModuleWithProviders = importedType;
  importedModuleType = moduleWithProviders.ngModule;
  if (moduleWithProviders.providers) {
    providers.push(...this._getProvidersMetadata(
        moduleWithProviders.providers, entryComponents,
        `provider for the NgModule '${stringifyType(importedModuleType)}'`, [],
            importedType));
    }
}
```

As we can see angular compiler takes providers from the object that will returned in withComponents method.

So, in order to merge your modules you can either use your approach(provide `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` in `LibModalModule.withProviders`) or reuse `A11yModalModule.withComponents` like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, A11yModalModule],
  providers: [LibModalService],
  exports: []
})
export class LibModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModalModule,
      providers: A11yModalModule.withComponents(components).providers
    };
  }
}
```

*(Tested with AOT)*

Also `A11yModalModule` has to be imported in `LibModalModule` if we want its providers to be included in our root module injector (And i suppose you're going to use `ModalService` and `DomService` that are declated in `A11yModalModule`). The reason of this is that angular includes all providers from transitive module in root module injector.

See also:

- [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular)
- [What you always wanted to know about Angular Dependency Injection tree](https://indepth.dev/posts/1261/what-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-angular-dependency-injection-tree)

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug that was giving me a false flag. Turns out you can just add the same `withComponents` method to the component library module and it passes the component through. I'd love an explanation on how this works if anyone knows.

```
// app module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalContentComponent],
  imports: [
    LibModalModule.withComponents([ModalContentComponent])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



// lib module
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, A11yModalModule],
  declarations: [LibModal],
  providers: [LibModalService],
  exports: []
})
export class LibModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModalModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        useValue: components,
        multi: true
      }]
    };
  }
}



// a11y modal module
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [ModalComponent],
  exports: [],
  providers: [ModalService, DomService],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent]
})
export class A11yModalModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: A11yModalModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        useValue: components,
        multi: true
      }]
    };
  }
}
```