# Angular module fabric

Tags: angular

I have a following module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AgPaginationComponent,
    AgGridNoRowsComponent,
    // a huge list of components
  ],
  exports: [AgPaginationComponent, AgGridModule],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    InputsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbPopoverModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      AgGridNoRowsComponent,
      // the same huge list from declarations
    ]),
    PipesModule,
  ]
})
export class MyAgGridAddonsModule { }
```

You see here that it's possible to configure `AgGridModule` by specifying a list of components in `withComponents` array. The idea behind `MyAgGridAddonsModule` module was to create one module that I can use every time when I need to initialize AgGridModule. But turns out the module is growing too fast and has too many components under `AgGridModule.withComponents` declaration. Now I want to have a possibility to specify which dependencies I want to use each particular time but in the same time copy base configuration that is the same for every case.

I want to accomplish something like

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyAgGridAddonsModule.withComponents([
      MyAgInputFilter,
      MyAgLiveSearchFilter,
      MyAgSelectFilter,
      MyAgDateCellRenderer,
    ])
  ]
})
export class MyAnotherModule { }
```

And the array of components from `MyAgGridAddonsModule.withComponents` should be passed down to `MyAgGridAddonsModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AgPaginationComponent,
    AgGridNoRowsComponent,
    // components passed down from MyAnotherModule
  ],
  exports: [AgPaginationComponent, AgGridModule],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    InputsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbPopoverModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      // components passed down from MyAnotherModule
      AgGridNoRowsComponent
    ]),
    PipesModule,
  ]
})
export class MyAgGridAddonsModule { }
```

Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this question and its answer if it helps- https://stackoverflow.com/q/49499984/3503019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `static withComponents(c: any[])` method and use `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` DI token (if not using `ivy`)  in your `MyAgGridAddonsModule` to register entry components that you'll pass from other modules -

```
// common ag grid entry components
const commonAgGridComponents: any[] = [RedComponentComponent];
@NgModule({    
  imports: [AgGridModule.withComponents(commonAgGridComponents)],
  exports: [AgGridModule]
})
export class AgGridCommonModule { 
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
     return {
      ngModule: AgGridCommonModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        useValue: components,
        multi: true
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

Then in your `MyAnotherModule`, import this AgGridCommonModule by passing the extra entry components -

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ AgGridCommonModule.withComponents(
            [GreenComponentComponent]
        ) ]
})
export class MyAnotherModule { }
```

Please checkout [this stackBlitz for AgGridModule](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-uog9zv?file=app/ag-grid-common.module.ts). `AgGridCommonModule` is a wrapper for `AgGridModule` where you pass the list of entry components via `withComponents()` method from any other module.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is define the shared components inside the `WithComponents` section, but for the other components define them as `frameworkComponents` inside the component.ts that uses the grid.

If you have a grid-component that you know is only going to be part of a particular grid, you can declare them in the component's module as normal components. If the component will likely be shared by another grid, you will need to create a module that exports the component to be used, since you can't declare the same component in 2 modules. This shared-module could also be used to replace `withComponents`, but would require the additional tying of `frameworkComponents` at each grid-component, which it sounds like you are trying to avoid.